# Laravel 5.4 - Connection timeout when Sending email with attachment using SMTP Gmail

Tags: email, laravel-5

When I am trying to sending an email without attachment, its working as well. But when I attach a file, its not working and give me this error message:

> Swift_TransportException Connection to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 Timed
>   Out

Here is my code:

```
...
public function build(){
  return $this
    ->subject('Welcome')
    ->markdown('emails.welcome')
    ->attach(storage_path('public/files/file.pdf'), [
        'as' => 'file.pdf',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf'
    ]);
}
...
```

Please help!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572907/using-gmail-smtp-via-laravel-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't think that was causing the issue. My issue is occurred  only when I try to sending email with an attachment.

Comment: I am also trying to send it using mailtrap.io and the issue still happened

Answer (score 0):

Use `realpath()` instead of `storage_path()`

So the code would be like this:

```
...
public function build(){
  return $this
    ->subject('Welcome')
    ->markdown('emails.welcome')
    ->attach(realpath('storage/files/file.pdf'), [
        'as' => 'file.pdf',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf'
    ]);
}
...
```