# Can't send email Laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, gmail-api, laravel-5.5, apache2.4

I'm trying to send email after user registration and I get an error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 server. Everything was ok on localhost.
Command

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2
```

returns OK, so I guess 587 port is opened to send email.
My `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=***@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*** //(not the same as I used on local machine)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

`config\mail.php`:

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', '***@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', '***'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

---

EDIT#1: also I have connected problem. While trying to seed this

```
public function run()
    {
        $defaultUser = User::create([
            'name' => 'user',
            'email' => 'user@mail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('123123'),
            'verified' => 1
        ]);

        $defaultAdmin = User::create([
            'name' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'admin@mail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('123123'),
            'verified' => 1
        ]);

        $userRole = Role::create([
            'name' => 'user',
            'display_name' => 'user',
            'description' => 'user',
        ]);

        $adminRole = Role::create([
            'name' => 'admin',
            'display_name' => 'admin',
            'description' => 'admin',
        ]);

        $defaultUser->attachRole($userRole); //zizaco-entrus RBAC package
        $defaultAdmin->attachRole($adminRole);
    }
```

only `$defaultUser` seeds (I have an event which fires after user is stored and send an verification mail to him). I get an error

> In StreamBuffer.php line 269:

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection ti
  med out #110]

EDIT#2: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` does not response.

EDIT#3: `sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
587/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
465/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
465/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

EDIT#4:
My new Gmail app key I created for this project is still unused.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28116200/9250371):

> In AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 419:
>   Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35469886/9250371) didn't help.

EDIT#5: checked smtp permission on server dashboard. Sorry for disturbing guys.

Comment: Your port might be wrong. did you try the alternates? 465 for example?

Comment: @catbadger yes, I tried 465, same error

Comment: might be dns. try pinging google.com?

Comment: @catbadger `7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6007ms
`

Comment: Could be a firewall issue.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide to set firewall...

Comment: Is this by chance a google cloud platform server?

Comment: @ajon [Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with GoDaddy servers that limit the number of relays your server can send out per day.

Google Cloud Platform prohibits the sending of emails altogether by blocking the commonly used SMTP email ports.  They do have agreements with the saas email providers to raise the number of free emails you can send.  For example, I use mailgun and instead of sending only 10,000 emails per month for free, I can send 30,000 emails.  I really like sending the emails this way because they have higher deliverability and allow us to track clicks, unsubscribes, views, etc easier.  Bottom line, I recommend subscribing to one of these services.

I suspect that Scaleway is limiting you as well.  Basically, any cloud server hosting service has a liability with emails.  Especially with shared hosting 1 spammer can flag multiple users across the same server and region as spammers even though they may be innocent.