# How can I solve "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com"?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, sendmail, laravel-forge

If I do send email on the my localhost, it works. No error

But I try on the staging server, it display error like this :

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

in StreamBuffer.php line 268
at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() in StreamBuffer.php line 62
at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => 'tcp', 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 'port' => '587', 'timeout' => '30', 'blocking' => '1', 'tls' => true, 'type' => '1', 'stream_context_options' => array())) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 113
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() in Mailer.php line 79
at Swift_Mailer->send(object(Swift_Message), array()) in Mailer.php line 395
at Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(object(Swift_Message)) in Mailer.php line 217
...
```

My env like this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

From some reference on the google ([Using gmail smtp via Laravel: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572907/using-gmail-smtp-via-laravel-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp)), I try some answer. I try change mail port and mail encryption to be like this :

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

It does not work

I try again to change this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

It does not work too

I do `on` here : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

It's the same

I try :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

It still does not work

My server using gitlab, forge laravel and digital ocean

Previous send mail on the staging server worked, but after I re-install the repository on the forge laravel, it now does not work

What do I need to set?

Comment: make sure the APP_KEY has been written in your .env file

Comment: Open this link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps Click on Enable. And save it. Then try to send email again. For me it worked .

Comment: @HirenGohel Do you not see the description in my question? I have tried it. But it's the same

Comment: Try to change driver in `.env` file like: `'driver' => 'sendmail',`

Comment: @HirenGohel I have tried all that. You try to watch carefully to my question

Comment: I see that, but you mentioned that you tried some answer. So that's why i told you to implement it!

Comment: @HirenGohel I had implement it. But it does not work

Comment: @SuYang The `APP_KEY` had been written in my .env file

Comment: I update my question with full error. Maybe you can solve the problem

Comment: Check this tutorial: [The connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com](https://devnote.in/the-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com/)

Answer (score 4):

Few days ago I've faced exactly the same problem and I've searched everywhere like laracast stackoverflow and many github issues and finally solve the problem.

You need configuration something like this,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

After this setup you should make sure that your google account `2 step verification` is turned off because this adds an extra layer of security that's why connection can't be established.

I think this is new feature added by google recently. I've working mail configuration before but recently same code doesn't work.

You can go to your google account where you will see **Sign-in and Security** tab. Click on it then you will see **2 step verfication** there. Then you need to turn off that. Then I think it'll work.

This thing worked for me I hope it'll work for you as well.
I hope you understand.

Comment: Like description on the my question, I had try change mail port and mail encryption like that. But it's the same. I just saw `2 step verfication` on the `Sign-in and Security ` in my account. It's `off`

Comment: Still not work ? I've the same issue and worked with above code. But I'm able to figure out how that work actually.

Comment: I update my question with full error. Maybe you can solve the problem

Comment: @SuccessMan I'll try

Comment: From this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572907/using-gmail-smtp-via-laravel-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp, I have tried all. Only 2 answers I have not tried. Answers from 李偉成 and John Foley. You try see it. I do not know where to set it. If you know that, you can give me another answer

Comment: What are you using your gmail password or application password ?

Comment: Yes, I using my gmail and my gmail password in the env

Comment: I've just have same problem when I change my current gmail at env file to my second gmail. But with application password it works perfectly. Have a try :D

Comment: I want to try answers from 李偉成 and John Foley on the link. But I don't know where to set it

Comment: @SuccessMan I also don't understand those answers

Comment: Okay. No problem. I just confused. Previously my send mail works. But when I re-install repository in my forge laravel. It becomes not working

Comment: I've exactly the similar issue but solved I'm not able to provide you the way to get out of the problem. Since I still don't know what the problem was in my case but solved.

Comment: In my localhost, it works. This just does not work on the staging server

Comment: @SuccessMan Any Errors ?

Comment: Same error. `Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]`

Answer (score 2):

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

You need to replace MAIL_DRIVER with MAIL_MAILER keyword in your env file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of send mail configuration in your staging server.
There are two solutions are available.
1) One is, create a email address with your domain name for ex, example@domainname.com then change the email config using the settings provided by your provider.
2) for another solution need to know your version of laravel.

Comment: okay my version 7.1.11 
and i tried the whole solutions and facing the same problem , 
so tell me please if you've more !

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention your server settings, I assumed this might be related to SELinux booleans.

If your SELinux is in enforcing mode, you need to turn on `httpd_can_sendmail` and `httpd_can_network_connect` booleans.

You can verify if SELinux status is enforcing by running this command:

```
$ sestatus
...
Current mode: enforcing
...
```

Check status of httpd sendmail and network connect booleans:

```
$ getsebool httpd_can_sendmail httpd_can_network_connect
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
```

To enable sendmail and network connect and make changes persistant across reboots:

```
$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```