# 500 (Internal Server Error) in Laravel while trying to send Mail in live server

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I want to make an online appointment in my Laravel project. For that I have generated a mail function for the appointment.This mail function is working in xammp server locally....But not in live server.

Got this error while trying to send mail

```
GET http://sencare.com.bd/sencare.com.bd/confirm_appointment?patient_name=test&patient_number=01654&patient_email=rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com&patient_age=8&patient_gender=1&service_id=6&schedule_time_id=1&date=+2018-03-27 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):2029
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

`log` file error

```
ERROR: Connection could not be established with host mail.mailhost.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution #0] {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host mail.mailhost.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution #0] at /home2/sencarec/public_html/sencare.com.bd/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269)
```

Mail function code inside controller

```
public function sendMail($emailDataArray)
{
 \Mail::send('frontend.mail.demo', $emailDataArray, function($message) use ($emailDataArray)
  {
    $message->to($emailDataArray['patient_email'], 'Test')->subject('APPOINTMENT');
  });
}
```

Here is my `.env` file's `MAIL` part

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=shetshuvro@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="app generated password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Anything change needed for live server or what's the problem actually ?

Comment: the error is not clear.

Comment: The error should be related to your server. 
check all the extensions are enabled.

Comment: @Jigs1212.... console give me that error

Comment: Also include laravel error log

Comment: @Jigs1212...update my post with error log...please check

Comment: have u checked the .env in the server ??

Comment: the error log is very clear ....

Comment: ya... I have already given the `.env` information in my post

Comment: Can u read my comment properly ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167223/discussion-between-raff-and-jigs1212).

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem.

Just change the driver name in `.env` file from `smtp` to `sendmail`

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
```

reference [[Using gmail smtp via Laravel: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572907/using-gmail-smtp-via-laravel-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp?noredirect=1&lq=1])