# Cannot send email from Laravel app in production

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send emails from Laravel app that I have in production, but it's not working.
It gives me this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
```

But when I try to send email from localhost it works correctly.

my config mail

1. MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
2. MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
3. MAIL_PORT=465
4. MAIL_USERNAME=*********
5. MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
6. MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

also email is less secure:on

Comment: @Miqayel have you found an answer to this problem?

Comment: @fred unfortunately no

Comment: @miqayel thanks for the response, I was struggling with the same issue, I ended up using sendgrid as suggested below. If you're still in need of a solution that would probably work.

Comment: have you tried `smtp.gmail.com` as mail host?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried it out?

[Using gmail smtp via Laravel: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572907/using-gmail-smtp-via-laravel-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp)

Also make sure your if your gmail account has 2 factor authentication enabled or not.

If there is any two factor authentication enabled in your account then you can use App specific password from google account page.

There are lots of services you can use like Sendinblue, sendgrid etc.

Comment: 2 Factor Auth is disabled, I've checked that also.